# Use java reflection to get an instance of a inner class

Tags: java, reflection

I have the following `School` class which contains a **inner** `Office` class:

```
class School {
    class Offcie {
        Office() {
          ...
        }
    }
}
```

In another place, I get an **instance** of `School` named `mySchool`.

The normal way to instantiate `Office` is :

```
School mySchool = new School();
Office myOffice = mySchool.new Office();
```

But how to use **java reflection** to get an **instance** of `Office` by using `mySchool` instance ?

Answer (score 0):

Get a reference to the `Office` parameterless `Constructor` and invoke it with a single argument, the `School` instance.

```
Constructor<Office> constructor = Office.class.getDeclaredConstructor(School.class);
Office office = constructor.newInstance(new School()); // or your instance
```

This is explained in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html)

> If the constructor's declaring class is an inner class in a non-static
>   context, the first argument to the constructor needs to be the
>   enclosing instance; see section 15.9.3 of The Java™ Language
>   Specification.

Comment: But I am not able to access Office class directly, the 'Office'  can not be found. I can only find by Class.forName("com.xx.yy.School$Office");

Comment: @user842225 Use `Class.forName`. It returns a `Class` object you can use. If you're getting a `ClassNotFoundException`, you have a different problem.